# android store photos to public directory and get access to their file system url

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm doing an android app with the capability to take pictures with the camera and send them to us, the company who distributes the app. Seems like an easy task, right? ;-)

The documentation describes how you are supposed to do it: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

It also says

> "Note: If you saved your photo to the directory provided by
>   getExternalFilesDir(), the media scanner cannot access the files
>   because they are private to your app."

Yeah, we are happy that we can store things privately, but I want our users to see their pictures in the gallery app. How do I store pictures to the public folder? The doc doesn't describe that.

Then, the doc describes that we should use `FileProvider.getUriForFile` which returns a `content://-uri`. Some `getContentResolver().query()` cursor mechanism is supposed to give me a real url to the filesystem, but it doesn't seem to work reliably and my upload class doesn't understand `content://-uris`. I get that we need security restrictions across package boundaries, but hey, I want the data back I just wrote! Is there a simple and reliable way to get a `file://-uri` for my pictures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I store pictures to the public folder?

Quoting [the documentation that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath):

> Generally, any photos that the user captures with the device camera should be saved on the device in the public external storage so they are accessible by all apps. The proper directory for shared photos is provided by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), with the DIRECTORY_PICTURES argument.

That being said, the specific passage that you quoted is incorrect. `getExternalFilesDir()` is *unique* for your app, but it is not *private* for your app. Photos stored in `getExternalFilesDir()` should be eligible for indexing via `MediaScannerConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You may specify the output path after a picture being snapped.

```
File newfile = new File("HERE IS YOUR OUTPUT PATH");
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

Hope it helps :)